# Quickblox iOS SDK: cannot send notification after signup

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios11, quickblox

I have an issue with QuickBlox iOS SDK.
I cannot send push notification just after signup.
it says next error with message "can't be blank Should contain 'payload' key"

here is some logs:

```
headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 72;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 06 Sep 2018 09:50:55 GMT";
    Duration = "0.434662";
    "QB-Token-ExpirationDate" = "2018-09-06 11:50:52 +0000";
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
    Server = "nginx/1.8.1";
    "Set-Cookie" = "_mkra_ctxt=0ba5f09e90b9d6de33bac4aeced2046e--422; 
path=/; max-age=5; HttpOnly; secure";
    Status = "422 Unprocessable Entity";
    "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000";
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
    "X-Request-Id" = "2420b421-6a3e-4433-8010-bdd82e6c8a9a";
    "X-Runtime" = "0.031619";
    "X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
}
error: Request failed: client error (422)
reasons: {
    errors =     {
        message =         (
            "can't be blank",
            "Should contain 'payload' key"
        );
    };
}
```

Though after I reopen the app (kill the process and open the app again) it works just fine.

**Environment details**
iOS Version                    11
Quickblox iOS SDK version      2.17.1
QuickbloxWebRTC SDK version    2.7
Xcode Version                  9.4.1

Answer (score 0):

just found an issue.
The issue is that for some reason quickblox does not allow to send some model inside payload only when signup. It works good from the second opening the app.

So had to remove sending user model ["user" : JSON string user model] from payload to simple [user_id : some string id].